# Why I am allowed to place and amp in this code?

Tags: c#

I have this sample code:

```
 DirectoryEntry _entry = new DirectoryEntry(
                    connectionString,
                    this.userPrinicipalName,
                    this.password,
                    AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer & AuthenticationTypes.Encryption);
```

How come I am allowed to make the amp in the last parameter? I am use to java where I have never seen this kind of witchcraft before AND I am new to C# - So can anyone tell me what it is and how I am allowed to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: see [C# Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) ...

Comment: [Bitwise AND operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody else has pointed this out, but

```
AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer & AuthenticationTypes.Encryption
```

is a bit weird because SecureSocketsLayer and Encryption are both 2.

So you might as well just put one or the other, not both...

If they *were* different and you *did* want to combine them, you should use the OR operator, |, not the AND operator, &.

Answer (score 2):

Those are probably integers, so you are just doing an binary `and (&)` of their values.

If you have 1 and 2 the result would be 0 `01 & 10 = 00`.

Comment: @Jon The net effect is the same, they have numeric values that get `bitwise and'ed`.

Comment: Sure, but that's IMHO a bad explanation. If I asked what `event += handler` does, would "it creates a delegate" be a good way to explain it?

Comment: @Jon I'm sorry if i did not use the correct terms. I am not familiar with the C# names as i code mostly C++ and C. Feel free to edit to change the names as appropriate.

Comment: That requires more editing than I am comfortable performing on an answer that isn't my own.

Answer (score 0):

[AuthenticationTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes.aspx) has a [FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx). Therefore you are able to combine different enumerated values into a composite enum value through for example bitwise OR operations.

Answer (score 0):

In this page [Authentication Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes.aspx). It says "This enumeration has a FlagsAttribute attribute that allows a bitwise combination of its member values." Meaning that each attribute has its own bit, so the bits can be combined to have multiple attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an enum that has the [Flags] attribute on it. This attribute allows bitwise operators to be used on the enum.